# HTML title extraction using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am working on developing an application in which I need to read a HTML file, for which I have decided to use Jsoup. But before diving into the actual application I wished to test a basic programming on extraction of title of a url using Jsoup. This is a stock code I have used just to check if the imported Jsoup libraries are working or not. But even in this code I am getting a error, and I cant proceed to my actual application with this not working. I have attached the code as well as error screenshot.

```
package dynamic_tester;
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
public class tester{  
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{  
    Document doc =   Jsoup.connect("http://www.javatpoint.com").get();  
                String title = doc.title();  
                System.out.println("title is: " + title);  
    }  
}
```

This is the error I am getting :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: java -cp jsoup.jar org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText url [selector]
>       at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
>       at org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText.main(HtmlToPlainText.java:35)

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Any suggestion why is it not working for me?
I have downloaded the Jsoup.jar file and included it as an external JAR file in this program

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: Looking at this comment of your, I checked the 'Run' option and it was running it as a 'html to plain text'. I changed it to 'java application' and its working for me now. Thank you @TDG